# Use "group_by" and "summarise" on some columns and keeping additional columns in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the `group_by` in R, then `summarise` while keeping extra columns in the data.

I just want to group by `id_trayecto`, but I want to include the other columns that are inside the `group_by`. The thing is that I don't know how to include them, without them being inside the `group_by`.

This is my code:

```
library(dplyr)

prueba <- reservas %>%
    group_by(id_trayecto, id_trayecto_dia, Van, fecha, hora) %>%
    summarize(Tickets.Vendidos = n(),
              Revenue = sum(Costo.final))
```

Thanks in advance guys :))

Comment: In the `group_by` function you should only have `id_trayecto`. The others will still be included. If you want to specify, which columns you want to have, use `select()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the `select`, but when I use `group_by` it doesnt add the other columns!

Comment: OK. Please provide data and I can check it. You can use function `dput(head(reserves))` and copy the output as a code to your question.  Otherwise, I think you have issue with `summarise` call. This is the one that only counts Tickets.Vendidos and Revenue... So, you should improve that call.

Comment: how can I improve the call `summarise`? Are you sure you want the `dput(head(reservas))`? It is very veeeeeeeeery long. I have approx 20k observations :(

Comment: `head()` inside `dput()` function limit the selection to only first 10 rows. Regarding `summarize()`, it will only give columns that you ask for.

Comment: Also the `select` call doesnt work, it gives me a weird error.

Comment: What info can I post in my question, so that it is easier to see what am I failing to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242015/discussion-between-bloxx-and-mateo-guajardo).

Comment: Generally we ask for reproducible examples - so you would post a few rows of your data in a copy/pasteable way, for example `dput(reservas[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows (choose a small subset that illustrates your problem). If you have `factor` columns, that might be too big, so you can use `droplevels()` to remove the ones that aren't present in the subset, e.g., `dput(droplevels(reservas[1:5, ]))`.  Then please show the desired output you want for that sample input.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on the cardinality between `id_trayecto` and the other columns in `reservas` that you want to keep.

To simplify, let's say you only want to keep `id_trayecto` and `fecha` after summarizing. If `reservas` in general can contain multiple values for `fecha` for a given value of `id_trayecto`, then what you want to do doesn't make sense, since summarizing by `id_trayecto` would possibly need to summarize across multiple values of `fecha`, so you'd either have to leave `fecha` out, or include it in the `summarize` statement with an appropriate aggregation function.

If, however, in `reservas` you only ever get the same value of `fecha` for a given value of `id_trayecto` than you can just include `fecha` in the `group_by` statement without it changing the results of the values `Tickets.Vendidos` and `Revenue`. Or in other words: Grouping and summarizing by the more granular variable is equivalent to grouping and summarizing by both variables.